# Is this a circular buffer?

Tags: buffer, stm32

I am programming STM32 using STM32CubeIDE.

As you can see from the code I am writing, all elements of the "*ADC_buffer*" are replaced with the next position element, except the last one .. which will be filled/replaced with the new sample read from the ADC.

```
      // Shift the buffer and store the last ADC data
      for(int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE-1; i++){
          ADC_buffer[i] = ADC_buffer[i+1];
      }
      ADC_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE-1] = ADC_Value;
```

**1)** Is this the implementation of a circular buffer?

**2)** If the answer is yes, what are the differences between these three lines of code I wrote and what a circular buffer set by STM32CubeMX would do?
(the image is only descriptive .. I'm not using DMA)

[image]

Comment: it is not circular buffer, to implement it correctly you need another variable to store "current position" in buffer and then do something like `ADC_buffer[position++] = ADC_Value; position = position % BUFFER_SIZE;` so position going in circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the implementation of a circular buffer?

No.  The key characteristic that makes a buffer "circular" is that, logically, it wraps around from the end back to the beginning.  That is, if one is writing into the buffer and reaches the last position, one continues at the first position (supposing that position is free, which it can be).  Similarly if one is reading.  A sense is always maintained of the range of positions that contain valid data, which frequently does not start at index 0.

One of the key advantages of a circular buffer, that justifies the extra metadata and more complicated implementation, is that one never has to move the data within the buffer.  That is, shifting the data down in the array, as your code does, is among the main things that a circular buffer avoids.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If the circular buffer does not move the data within the buffer as in my code ... then how does the data "rotate" within it? Isn't that also a "movement"? On a conceptual level I don't understand what the difference is because I obviously don't understand how it is physically implemented. Can you shed some light on this? Thank you. Do you think ilyaBursov's implementation is sufficient? Or do you think it is very sloppy?

Comment: @KaleM, the data *do not* rotate.  Being circular is about the logical topology of the buffer, and thus the behavior of readers and writers, not about movement of data within.  The specific code in Iłya's comment is an implementation of thsi part of this answer: "if one is writing into the buffer and reaches the last position, one continues at the first position".  His is a fine circular-buffer analog of the specific code you present in the question, but it is not a complete implementation of circular-buffer semantics. [...]

Comment: [...] For example, it does not address consuming data from the buffer, or testing whether the buffer is empty or full. And it does not address multi-item writes or reads -- support for these is not obligatory in general, but they are important for some uses.

Comment: @KaleM, If you want to think about something rotating in a circle, then it is the current write position and read position that do so.